# datetime, SELECT and prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want the same query to run twice with prepared statement, but cant get it to work?

Here is what I got:

```
$yearFrom = date("Y-01-01");
$yearTo = date("Y-12-31");

$monthFrom = date("Y-01-01");
$monthTo = date("Y-01-31");

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

$getuserpoints = "SELECT SUM(points) as userpoints FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
                    WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND fk_player_id = ?";

if($stmt->prepare($getuserpoints)){
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $yearFrom,$yearTo,$playerid);
    $stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($userPoints);

    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $monthFrom,$monthTo,$playerid);
    $stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($userMPoints);
}
```

I thinks is the datetime which is causing the trouble. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What do you mean by 'cant get it to work'? Are you getting an error message, is the second `$stmt->execute();` not executing, is the second `$stmt->execute();` executing with the firsts params?

Comment: Bugger... Found out I didn't fetch :-/ My bad. It works just fine now :-)

Comment: @Mansa: you're actually executing your query four times, not just twice. It doesn't really hurt in this case but still you should notice it because you could get unexpected results for other queries.